How to include condition of generated select to where parameter in Codeigniter 4?
My code in COdeigniter 4 model is as following:
public function check_header($id){
    $where_params = [
        'a.id' => $id,
        'fee_status' => 'applied'
    ];
    return $this->db->table('header a')
                    ->select('*, IF(NOW() BETWEEN a.fee_date_active AND a.fee_date_exp, "applied", "exp") AS fee_status')
                    ->where($where_params)
                    ->orderBy('a.id', 'DESC')
                    ->get()->getResult();
}

The problem is I include fee_status in the $where_params where fee_status is generated column from the select query above, returned an error from Codeigniter 4 that told me "Unknown column 'active_status' in 'where clause'".
How do I fix it? Thank you.

The answer is simply: you can't. See the answers to the duplicate question why and what else you can do instead.

You are only accessing one table, it is pointless to nominate a table alias in the first place.  See also getWhere()
